# Search for item name from multiple fields on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I'm trying to enable a search for an item, and then have that item listed if the search is completed. I can get it to work for both instances, but not at the same time. My code:

```
def search
    @results=0
        if !params[:searchinput].empty?
            @results=1
            @searchinput = params[:searchinput]
            @searchcriteria="%#{params[:searchinput]}%"
            @productlist = Product.where("productname like ? OR description like ?", @searchcriteria)
    end
end
```

I get the following error:
[image]
Is the formatting with the productlist statement wrong?

Comment: If you want to use the same term for both `?`s, you need to pass `@searchcriteria` twice; otherwise it thinks you forgot one.

Comment: @philomory I don't know how that passed over my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have to pass in two variables. If that is `@searchcriteria` then pass that in.

```
def search
    @results=0
        if !params[:searchinput].empty?
            @results=1
            @searchinput = params[:searchinput]
            @searchcriteria="%#{params[:searchinput]}%"
            @productlist = Product.where("productname like ? OR description like ?", @searchcriteria, @second_variable)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the productlist statement should look like the following:

```
@productlist = Product.where("productname like ? OR description like ?", @searchcriteria, @searchcriteria)
```